# why there is no firefox 94 version update for ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, updates, firefox

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, I've tried updating my firefox browser to the latest version, only the tar file is available on its website and we don't have the latest version on the this page also: `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/`
how do I get the latest firefox deb file now and are they going to release one for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: If you look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/ESM/16.04#Firefox_.2F_Thunderbird_.2F_LibreOffice  you'll note `firefox` is specifically covered for Ubuntu 16.04 ESM  (16.04 LTS being EOL with regards *standard* support and your provided link; upgrades do not appear on boxes *xenial* boxes that don't have ESM enabled)

Comment: Mozilla Team. Packages in “Firefox ESR and Thunderbird stable builds” for Xenial(firefox-95.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~mt1) https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS came out in April of 2016 and came with 5 years of support.

Community support has ended as of April 2021.  This means that it no longer gets bugfixes, security updates, and other software updates.

You can sign up for [Extended Security Maintenance (ESM)](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm) to receive critical updates, but ESM does not generally provide newer versions of software that are not essential.

It is strongly discouraged to use an EOL release.  You should install a [supported release](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop).